# Using Testcafe with TS Decorators?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, typescript-decorator

I am trying to combine decorators with testcafe hooks, however this doesn't work:
I am getting:

**Declaration expected** Error,
Is this can be achieving this? also with alternate solutions?

This:

```
fixture `Fixture 1`    
    .before(async() => {
        console.group('Fixture 1 before all tests of fixture 1 have started');
        console.log('Inside Fixture 1 before');
        console.groupEnd();
    })
```

Into:

```
fixture `Fixture 1` 
   @autoGroups
    .before(async() => {
        console.log('Inside Fixture 1 before');
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, decorators can be applied only to a class declaration, method, accessor, property, or parameter (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators).
You're trying to apply a decorator to the `before` function call, which is incorrect.

Please try the following approach:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

function methodDecorator (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    console.log("********************************");
}

class ClassWithDecorators {
    @methodDecorator
    before () {
        console.log('before');
    }
}

async function onBefore () {
    console.log('Inside Fixture 1 before');
}

fixture('Fixture 1')
    .page('http://example.com')
    .before(async () => new ClassWithDecorators().before());

test('test', async t => {
    await t.click('h1');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @alex-kamaev!
a few questions on the supposed solution:
<br/>
1. onBefore seems not to be in use
2. This solution will require to change every test I have, I was searching a way to "decorate" the before function even by another solution, the main point is that I don't want a massive change on existing tests (change from Fixture to DecoratorFixture is good from my POV)
hope this is a more clearer question

Comment: 1. My mistake. 2. Probably you can take a look at the Global Hooks mechanism: https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/advanced-guides/hooks#global-hooks

Comment: Thanks, I looked on it, it is indeed a great feature which I will use, however I can see how I can simulate decorators with it as it runs before/after test/fixtures.

In addition, the testcafe documentation (which is great) is not updated on that:
https://testcafe.io/documentation/403435/guides/advanced-guides/hooks#global-hooks
(also the global hooks example is wrong - missing "}")

mentioned in here:https://giters.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6855
the support of testcaferc.js is starting from testcafe 1.16 and it isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new issue regarding the mistake in the TestCafe documentation [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml).